# PositionError {code: 1, message: "Only secure origins are allowed ionic3?

Tags: geolocation, ionic3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>




<!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
  }
</script>-->

<link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
<ion-app></ion-app>

<!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

<!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
     It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

<!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
loadMap(){
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

     let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

     let mapOptions = {
         center: latLng,
         zoom: 15,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

     this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
   });
  }
```

I’m creating an app that needs to access get current location of the user but i got the position error in the chrome console and i have tried below link for resolve this issue :

> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/geolocation-not-possible-due-to-only-secure-origins-are-allowed-see-https-goo-gl-y0zknv/58678

but its not working for me as well as i tried other solution but not working for me and I have also generated the google map API key from the console and i have used below command:

> sudo ionic cordova run android --livereload

Since I get the same error in the emulator and when debugging on the phone, I am not sure how to resolve this error when dealing with Ionic. I use Ionic 3.9

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated, thanks!
below our index.html and home.ts file

Comment: try `ionic cordova run android` command

Comment: sir i have tried but got same error?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: sir check my updated fiddle i have update the index.html and home.ts file?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes i fixed it, problem is that tested in "run android" mode not in real device.after generating build its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this issue, and you are running on ionic4 just run

ionic cordova run android -livereload --ssl

in some cases, you'll be required to add an address, if that's the case use your public ip where your device is connecting

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-geolocation-only-secure-origins-are-allowed-error/61333/30

Also, this link has some insights about the issue:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ng-cordova/issues/1413

To clarify, this is not an ionic issue, it's due to some changes on the google policies.

In my case the location was working perfectly when running on the device, only failing when running with livereload option